# Can you do this with a database?

Tags: php, mysql, django, performance

I store all the videos and the details about each one in a database. I have some tables:

- video (details about the video, name etc.)
- video_file (each video is rendered with different bit rates and for different screen sizes)
- playlist (to store videos in predefined playlists)

Each video has files encoded for 1080 and 720, and each of those are again encoded with three different bit rates, and each of these bit rates are again encoded with both WebM and MP4. So there are six entries in the video_file per video entry. So my query returns 12 rows per video.

The problem I see is that for each row, ALL the information is included, not only the "neccecary" information. Example:

```
| id |   name   |    playlist    |   file   | quality | size | type |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  1     video1      funny videos     file1      3        720    MP4
  1     video1      funny videos     file2      2        720    MP4
  1     video1      funny videos     file3      1        720    MP4
  1     video1      funny videos     file4      3        1080   MP4
  1     video1      funny videos     file5      2        1080   MP4
  1     video1      funny videos     file6      1        1080   MP4
  1     video1      funny videos     file7      3        1080   WebM
  1     video1      funny videos     file8      2        1080   WebM
  1     video1      funny videos     file9      1        1080   WebM
  1     video1      funny videos     file10     3        720    WebM
  1     video1      funny videos     file11     2        720    WebM
  1     video1      funny videos     file12     1        720    WebM
```

This is an example output. What I would think would be much more effective is to group the results so that you get no redundant information from row to row, after all, you are going to group this information in PHP or the language you are using to be able to use it at all.

Example of what I believe would be more effective:

```
| id |   name   |    playlist    |   file   | quality | size | type |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  1     video1      funny videos     file1       3      1080    WebM
                                     file2                      MP4
                                     file3              720     WebM
                                     file4                      MP4
                                     file5       2      1080    WebM
                                     file6                      MP4
                                     file7              720     WebM
                                     file8                      MP4
                                     file9       1      1080    WebM
                                     file10                     MP4
                                     file11             720     WebM
                                     file12                     MP4
```

This way you can easily set up some variables corresponding to the column names:

```
id, name, playlist, file, quality, size, type

while (record = fetchRecord)
    id = record.id or id
    name = record.name or name
    playlist = record.playlist or playlist
    file = record.file or file
    quality = record.quality or quality
    size = record.size or size
    type = record.type or type

    // Now you have filled the variables with the exact information you had in the first recordset example, but without wasting so much unnecessary bandwidth and processing power.
```

Now, I'm adding in another table with notes that pop up during the video playback, so if there are x number of notes on a video, there will be 12x rows returned per video.

This is insane! Have I missed something? Is what I'm "explaining" here actually possible to do? Or is it better to make one query returning 12 rows per video like it is today, and run through each of the videos fetching the notes, or what?

This is the end of my question, thank you very much for reading this all the way through!

Comment: Is the last example I made actually how the data is transferred, but the client (for example PHP) does what the example code I posted does, so that it really is more effective behind the scenes?

Comment: perhaps `GROUP BY 'name'`

Comment: @Adsy2010 If I do that, I get only one row. Hmmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way to do something like this would be to use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function across the columns that differ, and group on the column(s) that repeat(s). This will create a delimited string column in the output that you will need to parse in PHP; however, it will reduce your row count to only the number of unique combinations of the non-grouped columns. For example:

```
select name, playlist, GROUP_CONCAT(file, '|', quality, '|', size, '|', type SEPARATOR '/') AS delimited_pairs
from video
group by name, playlist;
```

In the above example, the resulting `delimited_pairs` column will delimit each unique column value per name/playlist (the grouping columns) using the pipe character, and each of these unique combinations will be delimited by forward slash.

Comment: Hi Kim, yes classroom was my test table (forgot to replace it for the example), I'll edit it.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Thanks :) Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with your data layout. Your "redundant data" shouldn't go into the `video_file` table, but in the `video` table, as it is information referring to the video, not to the files! This database scheme is also bad in terms of cononsistency, if you eg. would update the the information in which playlist a video belongs you would have to do it for all the files...

Comment: Really? I have a table called video. It has got the video name/title and the description of the video. Then I have a table called video_files. It stores all the links to the physical files with information about their quality, size, type (WebM or MP4), and are connected to the video table by a foreign key video_id. Then I have a table playlist that contains the name of the playlist, and a description of it. Then I have a table connecting the playlist table and the video table in a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: So if I were to change which playlist a file belongs to, I would just change one entry in the playlist_video-table which connects playlist and video. I think maybe I've formulated myself poorly. The two "tables" you see, are actually the query results.

Comment: OK I see.. But that's not a real problem then.. Do you have encountered any real (performance) problems regarding this issue?

Comment: I haven't had many visitors, so no, I haven't had any problems with it. I'm just seeing that this is a waste of bandwidth, and that a world standard shouldn't be wasting this much bandwith, or I've misunderstood something. That's why I asked.

Comment: People are so afraid of their HTML-code being too long, but if this much bandwidth is wasted internally between the storage server and the other servers, I've got to have misunderstood something..